# Explanation for why "autocomplete" can't return a result, but Google Maps can

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

1. I search the URL, but it doesn't return a result (of course, with my key):

   > https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=4-29-12, Yotsuya, Shinjuku Ku, Tokyo To, 160-0004, Japan&sessiontoken=6624c831-104e-4eeb-a6ca-ff0b1f75e87c&language=zh_CN&location=35.552299,139.779999&strictbounds&radius=200000
2. But when I input this string into Google Maps, it returns the right place:

   > https://www.google.com/maps/dir//4-ch%C5%8Dme-29-12+Yotsuya,+Shinjuku+City,+T%C5%8Dky%C5%8D-to+160-0004%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC/@35.6882135,139.7101256,16z/data=!4m8!4m7!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x60188cebd619499d:0x3950c1ba3211a8d!2m2!1d139.7144922!2d35.6882049）
3. Why is it different?

Comment: One of the subjects of meta question *[Users doing Google first-level customer support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399137/users-doing-google-first-level-customer-support)*.

Answer (score -2):

This issue has been reported to our **public issue tracker**. You can star the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/144246527). This will subscribe you to receive technical updates on the issue. Starring the issue also provides us with valuable feedback on the importance of the issue to our customers, and increases the issue's priority with the product engineering team.

As a workaround for your issue for now, you can query the place from largest to smallest order: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=**Japan,Tokyo,Shinjuku, Yotsuya,4-29-12**&key=YOUR_API_KEY](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Japan,Tokyo,Shinjuku,%20Yotsuya,4-29-12&key=YOUR_API_KEY)